# -ms-filter opacity CSS property in IE8 produces ugly result

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8, opacity

To achieve image opacity in IE8, I'm using the following CSS property:

`-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=30)";`

However, the [resulting image](http://i0.simplest-image-hosting.net/picture/jira-capture-screenshot-20140924-181545-678.png) contains ugly artifacts. Is this a property of IE8 rendering engine? Are there any CSS-based workarounds?

Comment: Does just using '`filter: aplha(30);` not do the trick as well? (I wonder if it makes any difference, but none of this should be the problem...)

Comment: Is your PNG 24-bit? Try setting a non-transparent background color on the element that displays the image.

Comment: somethinghere: that produces only the artifacts without actually changing the opacity.

Comment: André Dion: it was a 32-bit PNG. The parent element already had white as background color. However, I tried changing the image to 24-bit PNG and it did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried targeting the image through CSS and just adding `opacity`? It should be covered by [all browsers now](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-opacity)

For example:

```
<div class="imgtarget">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com.s3.amazonaws.com/homepage-samples/408/287.jpg"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div.imgtarget img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvqqokr/1/)

Comment: Sorry, completely missed that part :(